# What would FAA controllers be referring to when mentioning "code 0027?"

Tags: air-traffic-control

In the second video on ["You Need To Hear These FAA Tapes From That Oregon UFO Incident That Sent F-15s Scrambling,"](http://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/18473/faa-recordings-deepen-mystery-surrounding-ufo-over-oregon-that-sent-f-15s-scrambling) you hear controllers mention a *code 0027*. If the target in question had a transponder, the content of the article is misleading. Does anyone know if *code 0027* refers to something specific in ATC terms, or are they just referring to a transponder code?

Here's the full link to the article. http://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/18473/faa-recordings-deepen-mystery-surrounding-ufo-over-oregon-that-sent-f-15s-scrambling

Comment: Hearing the phrase in context would be very helpful but I counted 5 videos on that page, some of them over 30 minutes long. Which one are you referring to and when exactly in the video does the phrase appear?

Comment: @Pondlife it's in the second video, the one with the radar and ATC synced, right at the beginning.

Comment: @Pondlife Revised.

Comment: @757toga I removed that from the question, but still, the reality of the matter is mundane compared to the implication.

Comment: @ryan1618 - agreed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the video the controller states that the target was a "**code**" 0027, which would indicate a transponder code.  Using ATC radar (in this case ARTCC) the controller can see what a secondary radar return (transponder) is squawking.  In this case apparently it's "0027" and displaying an altitude of 37,000 ft.

According to FAA Order 7110.66E entitled "National Beacon Code Allocation Plan (NBCAP)" code 0027 is assigned to ZAU (Chicago ARTCC) and is listed as IS-3 (code category) IS= Internal Departures - Special Use.

Here is the link [7110.66e](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FINAL_Order_7110_66E_NBCAP.pdf)

I have no clue as to why that transponder code is attached to that target in Oakland Center's airspace.

Comment: It sounds like the aircraft was squawking code 0027, but then it disappeared from both primary and secondary.

Comment: @ryan1618 - if you scroll down on the link to the video you provided, one of the commenters had a small screen shot of the radar display showing the target's limited data block displaying 0027 (txpnder code) and 370 (37000 ft altitude).  This data derives from a transponder.

Comment: @757toga Thanks. That's worth adding to the body of the answer.

Comment: 0027 may be assigned to ZAU, but i've personally observed at least 19 aircraft using that squawk over Los Angeles.  Interestingly, most of them seem to be Canadian.

Comment: @John it's very possible that the 00 block is assigned in some Canadian center for aircraft flying south into the US. Remember the 7110.66 is an FAA document; the Canadian system will almost certainly have been discussed and negotiated with the FAA, but the FAA's document will not prescribe what Canada does. The purpose of the allocation plan is to *prevent* aircraft from having to change codes while in flight, not to say "all aircraft entering this ARTCC will have their codes changed to these specific ones."